# Image function in google sheets wrong orientation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using the Image function in Google Sheets to display photos from my Google Drive but all the photos are rotated and I can't seem to find a way around this. I checked the photos on my Drive and they are in the right orientation, for some reason google sheets rotate them. Can you advise?

I'm using Google Apps Script Web App to take photos from my IPAD which will upload to my Drive and automatically display them in Google Sheets.
Can you help with this? Is there another way to display images in a cell other than the image function?

Here is a link for the image
[photo link I used in image function n Google Sheets](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1XQ7GTliF_fAMFCSzlzvb5PVg45PtYNyP)

Here is the code I'm using to upload images to my Drive and display them in Google Sheets

```
    function saveFile(obj) {
        const values = obj.map(({
            file,
            location,
            note
        }) => {
            if (file) {
                var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(file.data), file.mimeType, file.fileName);
                var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID HERE");
                var file = folder.createFile(blob);
                var fileId = file.getId();
                file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
                var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + fileId;
                var newurls = '=image("' + fileUrl + '",2)';
                return ["", newurls, new Date(), location, note];
            }
            return ["", "", new Date(), location, note];
        });
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // or var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
        var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Photos Report");
        ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
        //ws.getRange("M02").setValue("Send") ;    
        // return sendEmail();
        return "Success", sendEmail();

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script for inserting the image to Spreadsheet? And also, when you can provide a sample image for replicating your issue, I thought that it will help to think of the issue. By the way, I cannot understand about `Is there another way other than image function to display photos ?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I just edited my post , adding the code and a link for my photo .I meant if there is another way to display images in sheets other than " = image() "

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your additional information, I could correctly understand your situation. I have a question. In your goal, when the image is inserted to the cell, to reduce the image size is included in your direction of goal? Because when the image size is reduced, the image can be correctly inserted without the rotation.

Comment: Yes I would like to reduce image size  as well

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I suggested a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the images into the cells using Google Apps Script.
- In your goal, to reduce the image size is included.

#### Modification points:

- When I tested your image, I could understand about the issue. And, in that case, I could confirm that when the image size is reduced, the image can be inserted to the cell without the rotation. So in this answer, I would like to suggest to reduce the image size and insert it to the cell.
- In your script, when `var folder= DriveApp.getFolderById("ID HERE");` is put to the outside of the loop, I thought that the process cost will be reduced a little.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please enable Drive API at [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function saveFile(obj) {
  var folder= DriveApp.getFolderById("ID HERE");
  const values = obj.map(({file, location, note}) => {
    if (file) {
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(file.data), file.mimeType, file.fileName);
      var f = folder.createFile(blob);
      var link = Drive.Files.get(f.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s500");
      var blob2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, {headers: {authorization: "`Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob().setName("resized_" + f.getName());
      var ff = folder.createFile(blob2);
      ff.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+ff.getId();
      var newurls = '=image("'+fileUrl+'",2)';
      return ["", newurls, new Date(), location, note];
    }
    return ["", "", new Date(), location, note];
  });
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // or var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Photos Report");
  ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  //ws.getRange("M02").setValue("Send") ;
  // return sendEmail();
  return "Success",sendEmail();
}
```

- In this modified script, it uses the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the original image from the file.
  2. Retrieve the thumbnail URL of the image, and modify the URL for changing the image size.

     - At this sample, it uses 500 pixels in the width as a sample. When you want to modify this, please modify `"=s500"`.
  3. Retrieve the blob from the thumbnail URL and save it as a file.
  4. Insert the image to the cell using the image file.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)